# Prisma - SQL Server - Wrong catalog

Tags: prisma

I'm trying to initialize the database with Prisma using the following command:

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name init
```

However, it complains that my database is not in sync and shows me table names from **another database** and ask if I want to reset it.

Here is the schema:

```js
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
    provider = "sqlserver"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Test {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
}
```

And the connection string:
`sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initialCatalog=sample;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;`

The catalog "sample" is defined there, but for some reason, it is trying to connect to another existing database.

I tried to create the "sample" database manually but it doesn't change anything.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed `initialCatalog` to `database` and it's working.

`sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;database=sample;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;`